# GLSL Normal Mapping (Areas With 0.0 Lambert Gets Lit)

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, assimp, bump-mapping

when i use the model's normal , the result is fine ( there are dark areas and lit areas , as i would expect from a simple lambert diffuse shader )

but when i use a normal map , the dark areas gets lit!

i want to use a normal map and still get correct diffuse lighting like these examples

here is the code with and without normal mapping

and here is the code that uses the normal map

Vertex Shader

```
varying vec3 normal,lightDir;
attribute vec3 vertex,normalVec,tangent;
attribute vec2 UV;

void main(){

gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * vec4(UV,0.0,0.0);
normal = normalize (gl_NormalMatrix * normalVec);
vec3 t = normalize (gl_NormalMatrix * tangent);
vec3 b = cross (normal, t);
vec3 vertexPosition = normalize(vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * vec4(vertex,1.0)));
vec3 v;
v.x = dot (lightDir, t);
v.y = dot (lightDir, b);
v.z = dot (lightDir, normal);
lightDir = normalize (v);
lightDir = normalize(vec3(1.0,0.5,1.0) - vertexPosition);
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*vec4(vertex,1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
vec4 computeDiffuseLight (const in vec3 direction, const in vec4 lightcolor, const in vec3 normal, const in vec4 mydiffuse){

float nDotL = dot(normal, direction);
vec4 lambert = mydiffuse * lightcolor * max (nDotL, 0.0);
return lambert;
}

varying vec3 normal,lightDir;
uniform sampler2D textures[8];

void main(){
vec3 normalVector = normalize( 2 * texture2D(textures[0],gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb - 1 );
vec4 diffuse = computeDiffuseLight (lightDir, vec4(1,1,1,1) , normalVector, vec4(0.7,0.7,0.7,0));
gl_FragColor = diffuse ;
}
```

Note: the actual normal mapping works correctly as seen in the specular highlights

i used Assimp to load the model ( md5mesh ) and calculated the tangents using Assimp too , then sent it to the shaders as an attribute

here is a link to the code and screenshots of the problem

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32670019/code%20and%20screenshots.zip

is that a problem in the code or am i having a misconception ?

**Updated code and screenshots**

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32670019/updated%20code%20and%20screenshots.zip

now the normal map works with the diffuse , but the diffuse alone is not correct

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?

Comment: oh i forgot to include them , i am using 1.10 , i will include them thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Answer, see below.**

Quick (possibly wrong) observation:
The line

```
vec3 normalVector = normalize( 2 * texture2D(textures[0],gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb - 1 );
```

in your fragment shader correctly rescales your normal to allow for negative values. If your normal map is incorrect, negative values might occur where you do not want them (your Y axis I presume). Negative values in a normal can result in reversed lighting.

My question to you: Is your normal map correct?

**ANSWER**: After a bit of discussion we found the problem, I've edited this post to keep the thread clean, the solution to Darko's problems are in the comments here. It came down to uninitialized varying called lightDir.

Original comment:

lightDir = normalize (v); lightDir = normalize(vec3(1.0,0.5,1.0) - vertexPosition); This is strange, you overwrite it instantly, is this wrong? you dont seem to keep the correctly translated lightDir... Or am I crazy... Also this lightDir is a varying, but you don't set it at all. So you calculate a v vector from nothing?

Comment: nice observation =] , but yes the normal map is correct , i have tried many normal maps from working examples already , the same normal map i am using is the same one the "original" screenshots are using

Comment: Now that I'm alowed to comment :), please upload your non-normal shader code here aswell as in the zip, it seems to be missing.

Comment: I would *print* (output) the normal, tangent and bitangent as colors I believe they are not correct and doesn't transform into tangent space correctly. If you take a closer look, bumpmap shadowos are not correct either.

Comment: =D , i think i did , isn't there 4 source files and 4 images in the zip file ? , its called "withoutNormalMap"

Comment: lightDir = normalize (v);
lightDir = normalize(vec3(1.0,0.5,1.0) - vertexPosition);
This is strange, you overwrite it instantly, is this wrong? you dont seem to keep the correctly translated lightDir... Or am I crazy...
Also this lightDir is a varying, but you don't set it at all. So you calculate a v vector from nothing?

Comment: No, i have seen similar problems due to wrong generation of tangent basis. I would just make three screen shots: 1 outputing the normal per pixels as rgb color (gl_FragColor = normal), 2 tangent, 3 light. This helps spot if the tangent basis are ok

Comment: hmmm , this DOES look strange , probably this is the error , i will fix it and let you know , give me a minute

Comment: Also this lightDir is a varying, but you don't set it at all. So you calculate a v vector from nothing?  (duplicate from edit) Please update your code when you have fixed these problems

Comment: @FullFrontalNudity , that was the problem indeed , but it created a new problem that i tired to explain but couldn't , now the normal mapping works but the diffuse shader alone doesn't work ! :D
check the new link above with updated stuff

Comment: @Trax ,i see , and what is the expected output of each screen shot so i conclude that the tangent basis are ok or not ? and what do you mean by light ? light direction in which space exactly ? please tell me more about this nice debugging technique =]

Comment: colors should have a nice gradient across the surface, without big jumps in color (but probably change at texture seams). If they are not, then something is not ok. I mean you can also output light in tangent space.

Comment: You are still transforming your lightdir to tangent space in your diffuse shader, i dont think you should. Keep it at this: lightDir = normalize(vec3(1.0,0.5,1.0) - vertexPosition); Looking at your screenshots, your tangent calculations are most likely fine.

Comment: if i did that , then what will be the use of the tangent space ? , this is the only thing that i use the tangent space conversion for, so when i remove this it won't be a normal mapping shader ( i also tried it now , the normal map won't work any more )

Comment: If you intend to make two shaders, one with normal map, and one without. And only the one without is not working, then why not just revert it back to the way it was? You don't need all the normal map stuff if you dont use it anyway. Perhaps I don't understand what is wrong exactly?

Comment: well , you have a point there , i could just make two shaders and that would work , i will settle with that solution =] , Thanks alot can you please write your 3rd comment ( the one that solved the original problem ) in a post so i can vote it to give you reputation points ? :) , you too @Trax please post your comment about the different screenshots in an answer so i can vote it :) , thank you all :)

Comment: Edited the main post to contain the solution, though I'm not sure how much use it will be for future visitors.

Comment: it probably won't be of much use , i just wanted to give you your earned credit , i couldn't vote though =[